# Replace command using post.context to add new line

Tags: powershell, replace, line-breaks

Trying to add a line break here but it's not working. Tried also using the `` `r ``, but no luck.

My code:

```
$extract = @()
Select-String -Path $outfile -Pattern "text" -Context 0,12 |
    ForEach-Object {
        $extract += $_.Line | foreach {$_.Replace("text", "DD/MM")}
        $extract += $_.Context.PostContext | foreach {$_.Replace(',', "`n")}
    }
$extract | Out-File $outfile1
```

My Input:

```
DD/MM
27,28
14
21
1
15
7
12
2,15
25
```

What I'm trying to do is to add a line break for 27,28 and 2,15 so it reads each number in a separate line:

```
27
28
2
15
```

Any idea why the replace is not working here?

Comment: Please provide sample input.

Comment: The input $outfile is same as output, I was able to replace the comma by any other character or nothing but when I try to replace comma by a new line, it does not work.                                                                DD/MM
27,28
14
21
1
15
7
12
2,15
25

Comment: The code you posted would already handle that.

Comment: I agree, but the sad part is: it doesn´t :( I´m using powershell 4.0, don´t know if something with this version, but anyway, will keep trying. I appreciate your help here anyway.

Comment: Found it!!!! :) I forgot to add the `r, so now it´s working as I wanted.... :D